# Spring Boot AWS MSK Configuration

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, apache-kafka, aws-msk

To consume messages from Kafka, I am using the below configuration in my local. It is working fine.

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id: order-events
spring.kafka.admin.properties.bootstrap.servers: localhost:9092
```

In DEV, SIT Kubernates cluster, we are using Amazon MSK. The below details are shared.

Host:   **z3.kafka-central-1.amazonaws.com:9096,z1.kafka-central-1.amazonaws.com:9096,z2.kafka-central-1.amazonaws.com:9096**

**Configuration**:  3 Partitions, 3 Replicas, 3 Brokers, 3 Different AZs, SASL/SCRAM authentication, retention.ms=604800000, max.message.bytes=2097164

**VPC Id**: vpc-123sdfsdf234

**AWS Account** 123456789

**CIDR**    10.20.1.1/24

**Username**    user-msk-kafka-user

**Password**    XXXXXXXX

What are the properties, i should configure in spring application properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Your MSK VPC CIDR `10.20.1.1/24` is private.

Make sure your Dev/SIT the environment you are using to connect to MSK is in same VPC `vpc-123sdfsdf234`. If it's inside same VPC, check MSK security group to make sure your CIDR range `10.20.1.1/24` is whitelisted with the required ports.

Otherwise create MSK with Public IP's.

Comment: How to identify MSK VPC CIDR is private or public. How to configure the configuration details in spring applicaiton.properties